# Unusual behavior posting multiple PHP fields . Get only the first one

Tags: php, html, ajax, http-post

I'm working on a web-application which essentially consists of a huge html form. This form is composed of several itemized lists, dynamically loaded by Ajax when the parent of a specific child list is inserted. The html code relative to 'child list' is something like :

```html
<div id="child_list_one">
  <div class="child">
      <input type="text" name="list_one_name[]" value="CHILD ONE NAME"/>
      <input type="number" name="list_one_quant[]" value="10"/>
      <input type="number" name="list_one_price[]" value="10.10"/>
  </div>
  <div class="child">
      <input type="text" name="list_one_name[]" value="CHILD TWO NAME"/>
      <input type="number" name="list_one_quant[]" value="20"/>
      <input type="number" name="list_one_price[]" value="20"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

**PROBLEM:** when the post request is triggered, on server side (using PHP), the $_POST variable  should contain several arrays with form data, but I get only the first occurence for each array. Something like:

```
["list_one_name"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string "CHILD ONE NAME" } 
["list_one_quant"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int 10 } 
["list_one_price"]=> array(1) { [0]=> float 10.10 }
```

The odd thing is this code is working as aspected on localhost and even on a domain created on Altervista.org for testing, but not on production server.
I'm starting to think that this problem is somehow related to Apache configuration but I can't figure it out. I hope some of you have already encountered this kind of problem.

---

**UPDATE :** The following code shows that my problem is related to PHP version or its configuration :

```
echo file_get_contents("php://input");
print_r($_POST);
```

Getting the standard input through file_get_contents, I'm now sure that all my data are indeed received by PHP and are not filtered by Apache. Anyway PHP does not automatically decode indexed form variable names and not all data are contained in the $_POST variable. It seems to brutally ignore indexes different from zero. This behavior concerns only the input names in the form of 'INPUT_NAME[ ]'.

Why this happen only on production server ?

**Apache v. :** 2.0

**PHP v. :** 5.3.8 with Suhosin v0.9.32.1

Comment: try to open both php.ini and do confront them

Comment: that said it can ben indepth ini set -> max_input_nesting_level -> http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-nesting-level

Comment: @MarcoMura thanks for quick reply. Indeed max_input_nesting_level was commented out. I set it with a value of 64 even if in my case the nested level is 1. Anyway the problem persists ...

Comment: max_input_vars integer are setted ok?

Comment: @MarcoMura yes with a value of 1000

Comment: If you've got apache server then you can check for filter, like http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_mime.html#addinputfilter or http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#setinputfilter